# Find first N rows that have unique value with mod(id, N)

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, N is 10 and a table looks like

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
10
11
12
13
108
109
111
112
113
```

Need to find first N rows that have unique value with mod(id, N).

Expected result is

```
mod10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
10
108
109
```

I've tried something like

```
select * 
from 
(
    select id, id % 10 as seq_id
    from accounts order by id
) as s1 
group by s1.seq_id limit 10;`
```

but not working.

Comment: explain "but not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function here -

```
SELECT id
  FROM (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id % 10 ORDER BY id) RN
          FROM table_name
       ) X
 WHERE RN = 1
 ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below one - using `row_number()`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2e9864f202a9375e03c45553b3a3f6c6)**

```
with cte as
(
select id, row_number() over(partition by seq_id order by id) as rn
from
(
select id, id % 10 as seq_id from tablename
)A 
)

select id from cte where rn=1 order by id
```

OUTPUT:

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
10
108
109
```

Comment: @MaciejLos, now it's in postgres - check here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2e9864f202a9375e03c45553b3a3f6c6